# Sending commands to gdb from the debugged program

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

Is it possible to control gdb from the debugged program? I'm hoping for a library that can help with this, ideally with an API such as `gdb_sendcmd("bt")`, but I can live with something like connecting to local gdb via a socket.

Primary use case is programmatically adding a data breakpoint to monitor when a certain memory address next gets modified. Target language is, naturally, C; anything applicable to it can be reused with C++ and Objective-C.

---

[Answer from Employed Russian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9026975/39974) has solved my direct problem, but I'd still love to know how I can run GDB commands programmatically from the debugged program. It may speed up some debugging if I could simply add code to the project instead of writing extra startup commands for GDB that would create breakpoints with attached commands.

So if there is a way to run commands programmatically, I'd still love to hear it ;)

Comment: I'm pretty sure this can't be done.  You can write some scripts for GDB in Python, apparently, but how to automatically invoke them, say, when a breakpoint is hit, to create that memory watch you are asking for, is not clear to me.

Comment: Many CPU architectures have HW support for this kind of thing with data breakpoints, data watchpoints, instructions that cause breaks, etc.

Comment: @TJD Exactly -- but I wanted to know how to trigger setting data breakpoint programmatically in gdb, or how to run any other command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Python interface exported by GDB allows you to do many things. Maybe something like this would fit your requirements:

```
import gdb

CMD_FCT  = "gdb_run" 
CMD_NAME = "str"

class GdbRunBreakpoint(gdb.Breakpoint):
    def __init__(self):
        gdb.Breakpoint.__init__(self, CMD_FCT, internal=1)
        self.silent = True

    def stop(self):
        cmd = gdb.parse_and_eval(CMD_NAME).string()
        gdb.execute(cmd)
        return False
GdbRunBreakpoint()
```

(just write than in a file, and source it from your `.gdbinit` file)

and on the application side:

```
void gdb_run(char *str) {}


int main () {
    gdb_run("where");
}
```

I think the code is straight forward, but as I mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/8884512/341106, not everything is allowed in the `stop` callback, GDB is in an intermediate state, but many things will work as expected.

**EDIT:** needless to say, this won't work if you app is not compiled with debug symbols!

Comment: I'm accepting the answer, despite being unable to actually get this to work on OS X. This is probably due to GDB shipping with Xcode 4 being  6.3.5, while I see you mentioned 7.4 in your other answer. Hence, Python is probably unsupported: `.gdbinit:1: Error in sourced command file:<newline>helper.py:3: Error in sourced command file:<newline>Undefined command: "import".  Try "help".`. I do understand what's going on, though, and it seems to be exactly what I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: @Ivan oh yeah, 6.3 is a bit old, Nov 2004 according to their website, the Python support was introduced 5 years after ;)

Comment: Side note, gdb.execute accepts a \n-separated string to execute multiple commands too. Convenient in this case. // Also if you want to run in the frame of the caller, add a `up` in the code.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to control gdb from the debugged program?

No. If the program could do that, and (say) disabled all breakpoints, how would you debug it?

> Primary use case is programmatically adding a data breakpoint to monitor when a certain memory address next gets modified.

This often comes up in a context like this: on Nth invocation of `foo()`, a (local or global) variable `bar` gets unexpectedly clobbered, and you want to find the culprit.

If that is indeed your problem, then set a breakpoint on the line where you know the value of `bar` is still good (just after it has been initialized). Set ignore count (using `ignore` command) on that breakpoint to `N-1`, and then, when the breakpoint is hit, set the watchpoint on `bar`.

You can even attach commands to the breakpoint:

```
commands 1   # assuming this was the first breakpoint
 watch bar
 continue
end
```

so the watchpoint is attached automatically.

Comment: Program being allowed to drive gdb (and possibly disable breakpoints) isn't an issue for me during development; having inserted function call that disabled breakpoints, I can also easily remove it. *However*, your idea of attaching commands to breakpoints sounds interesting and solves my problem. I'd still love to see if someone has an idea how to run a command programmatically.