# How can I make a C++ function that can pretty print every object, using gdb?

Tags: c++, gdb

In linux, with gdb debugger I can print every object if the program is compiled with `-g` option. Is it possible to write a function like

```
template<typename T> ostream& to_stream(ostream& out, const T& obj);
```

that serialize my object with the name and type?

Naturally with help of gdb call or system call or other.

Comment: We need more details. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Are you looking for some debugging information API for C++?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have gdb, you can't do much.

`magic_get` works in some limited cases.

For the rest you mostly have to manually specify the field names, possibly through a macro to make it more convenient, but still manual.

[visual c++ - Printing values of all fields in a C++ structure - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758937/printing-values-of-all-fields-in-a-c-structure)

---

If you have gdb (as in, you can **guarantee** the program will be run in gdb) however, (as specified in the question),
use a technique in
[c - Sending commands to gdb from the debugged program - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9026279/sending-commands-to-gdb-from-the-debugged-program)
we have (you need the Python code copied from that post run in gdb)

```cpp
void gdb_run([[maybe_unused]] char const* str) {}

template<class T> void gdb_pretty_print([[maybe_unused]] T const& arg){
    gdb_run("up\nprint arg");
}

struct Example{
    int a;
    char b;
};

int main(){
    gdb_pretty_print(Example{1, '0'});
}
```

If you want to get the result to pass to C++ you can do something like

```
template<class T> void gdb_pretty_print([[maybe_unused]] T const& arg){
    char const* volatile result=nullptr;
    gdb_run("up\n"
            "python gdb.set_convenience_variable('result', gdb.execute('print arg', to_string=True))\n"
            "set result=$result");
    __builtin_printf("result = %s\n", result);
}
```

Actually I'm not sure if `volatile` will do it, alternatively compile the particular with `-O0`.

---

Alternatively you may try to set break point within `gdb_pretty_print` itself, but I tried it's pretty hard.

```py
class GdbPrettyPrint(gdb.Breakpoint):
    def __init__(self, function_name):
        super().__init__(function_name, internal=1)
        self.silent = True

    def stop(self):
        gdb.execute("print arg")
        return False

def set_breaks():
    for b in gdb.rbreak("^gdb_pretty_print<"):
        GdbPrettyPrint(b.location.split(":")[-1])
        b.delete()
```

You have to run the `set_breaks()` function unfortunately. For some reason `rbreak` alone doesn't work for me.

Example program

```cpp
template<class T> void gdb_pretty_print(T const& arg){
    (void) arg;
}

struct Example{
    int a;
    char b;
};

int main(){
    gdb_pretty_print(Example{1, '0'});
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can do it with python [Pretty Printing API](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Pretty-Printing.html#Pretty-Printing). To start with pretty printing, you can look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12574253/72178) and Tom Tromey's blog: http://tromey.com/blog/?p=524.

Comment: (I didn't downvote but) I think you misunderstood the question. it asks for how to write C++ function (even before the recent edit)