# Debugging a programmatically called function with GDB

Tags: c, gdb

I am debugging a piece of software for an ARM32. I have been able to programmatically call functions in GDB using `call`, or even `print`. The problem is that I cannot seem to be able to set a breakpoint on a function, and then call it programmatically. For example, if I do:

```
break test_function
call test_function()
```

then I get the error message

> The program being debugged stopped while in a function called from
>   GDB. Evaluation of the expression containing the function. When the
>   function is done executing, GDB will silently stop.

Is there a way to programmatically call a function using GDB *and* step through it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> then I get the error message
>
> `The program being debugged stopped while in a function called from GDB. Evaluation of the expression containing the function. When the function is done executing, GDB will silently stop.`

This isn't an error. This is *exactly* what you wanted to happen: a breakpoint fired, and you are now ready to debug.

Comment: Thanks. I got confused by the fact that the message "removed" the `(gdb)` prompt. I didn't realise I could continue debugging.

Comment: This is considered an error. When you run gdb in `-batch` mode this scenario triggers an error and exits gdb. Sure, when debugging manually, this message can be ignored, but I could not find a way to suppress this when running gdb scripts.

Comment: I would also like to suppress this message when letting gdb automatically execute commands from a gdb script file. In interactive mode this message is presented as a informational note. In scripted mode, this message is interpreted as an error. Which I think is not nice. At least not for my use case.